# Push to github in Zend Studio 9 error

Tags: github, push, zend-studio

I'm using Zend Studio 9.0.3 and I have a repository on github. I created a project from github on my local machine. I can commit things, but once I try to push to upstream, I get the following error:

Can't connect to any repository: https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.git (An internal Exception occurred during push: https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.git: insufficient data written)

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance for any info!

(nb: replaced the actual url with xxxx - don't want anyone sniffing in it while it's in development =] )

## edit:

I don't get that error anymore, but now Zend Studio thinks the master/origin repository is already up-to-date, while there are several commits waiting to be pushed.

Answer (score 0):

I had simillar errors while creating two (or more) branches of code, then merging them, commit, and push. I guess this is caused by some bugs in git algorithm.

Comment: I'm actually pushing my changes directly to the master branch. My IDE thinks the repository is already up to date when I try to push things, while there are 4 commits waiting to be pushed at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

Steps I took to fix this:

1. Open Preferences -> General -> Network -> generate new SSH (RSA) key
2. Go to github, add the key to your keys
3. Removed the default revs settings that Zend studio made
4. Pushed to origin/master.
5. Success \o/